# Use of radio buttons and sliders in PHP APIs

Tags: php, json

I have read about creating REST APIs and i have decided to give it a go, the create aspect deals with inputting values to fields and then storing those fields in an sql db... but what about radio buttons and sliders for choices and yes or no questions? how can you implement those into an API?

Comment: All these controls have underlying values, those will get submitted / retrieved through the api.

Comment: @Shadow so is there anyway the api is coded such to get these values and put them into the db? im trying to test using postman

Comment: The API will not even know what controls set the parameters, that's the beauty of APIs! Different developers can implement different user interfaces that rely on the same API. All that matters is that the UI must call the right API endpoints with the right parameters. So, the controls are handled in the UI, not in the API.